# How to extract a land cover type from Corine Land Cover raster in R

Tags: raster, r, raster-calculator

I would like to know how I can extract a certain land cover type from a CORINE raster (GeoTiff) in R. I have the .tif file read in using `raster` function from raster package.

How can I binarize this raster so that land cover "Pasture" land cover type, which happened to have the value 231, is converted into 1 and all the others are turned into 0. Below is a piece of code you can use to explain your answer. I would like to save this new raster as a new raster.

```
raster("CLC2018_CLC2018_V2018_20.tif") -> corine   # Read in using raster function from raster package
plot(corine) # Gives the map below.
```

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing your raster with a numeric value results in a 1 for TRUE and a 0 for FALSE. This should work, I can't test it without your data file.

```
corine <- raster("CLC2018_CLC2018_V2018_20.tif")  
pasture <- corine == 231
```

show it:

```
plot(pasture)
```

get a table of pasture/non-pasture cells:

```
table(pasture[])
```